# Nested for loops for directory in bash script

Tags: bash, nested

```
for d in dirlist;  
do  
    cd $d  
    echo $PWD "primul"  
    for p in *.HEIC;  
    do  
        echo $PWD "din al doilea"  
        if [ -e "COPY ${p%.*}.jpg" ]; then  
            echo "COPY ${p%.*}.jpg exists"  
        else  
            convert $p "COPY ${p%.*}.jpg"  
            echo "COPY ${p%.*}.jpg created"  
        fi  
    done  
done
```

I have written a script to convert all files that are .HEIC to .jpg. Now I have a structure of folders that is

```
/main/2019/01  
/main/2019/03  
/main/2018/12  
/main/2018/11  
/main/2018/10  
/main/2018/09
```

And I want to run the second for in each directory.

What I get when I run the commands below is only a list of directories and a mention that there are no files to convert.

How do I change the directory using the first for and run the second for in that directory?

Comment: please provide the output and/or error produced by your script

Comment: After the first iteration, `cd $d` in the next iteration will look for `$d` inside the previous directory in the list, unless you give a list of absolute pathnames.

Comment: Use `cd -` after closing the inner for.

Answer (score 0):

`cd -` changes to the previous directory. That one solution to put it after the first `done` (second for cycle).
`pushd` and `popd` using stack to handle directory changes

check out: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Directory-Stack-Builtins.html